# How does the [UK] Office of National Statistics make allowances for incomplete census information?

Tags: statistical-inference

I entered into a rather ill-tempered argument with a stranger yesterday. It started going downhill when he asserted that there were in fact 90 million people in the United Kingdom, not the 60 that I quoted from my memory of the last time I looked at the ONS figures.
"But they miss all the illegals," he said.

Whilst of course census information is always inaccurate and incomplete, I was wondering what methods the ONS uses to compensate for this in order to produce a figure good enough for the government to use.

Comment: So this person claims that every 3rd person in the uk is illegal?

Comment: @user619894 That was his misinformed assertion, yes. After a few pints I found it difficult to get beyond the racist assumption there, but to dredge a little bit of usefulness out of it, it did set me wondering about how the ONS gets round the problem that such an important, consequence-laden study as a census, is faulty.